# Replacing multidimensional array with another one?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, replace, char

I'm making an 2D Game to train my class managment.

I have two multidimensional arrays: `Map1` and `Map`. I want to replace `Map` values with `Map1` ones. How can I do this without replacing every element manually like `Map[0][0] = '#'` etc.

```
char Map[10][21] = {
    "####################",
    "#                  #",
    "#                  #",
    "#                  #",
    "#                  #",
    "#                  #",
    "#                  #",
    "#                  #",
    "#                  #",
    "####################"};

char Map1[10][21] = {
"####################",
"#                  #",
"#                  #",
"#                  #",
"#                  #",
"#       TEST       #",
"#                  #",
"#                  #",
"#                  #",
"####################"};
```

Answer (score 1):

Since multi-dimensional arrays are guaranteed to be contiguous in memory layout, **and the two arrays have the same size**, you can do this:

```
std::copy((char*)Map1, (char*)Map1 + sizeof(Map1), (char*)Map);
```

Note that the cast is necessary to make the whole copy as a array of char.

On the other hand, this task would have been more straightforward if you used `std::vector<std::string>`, you could directly assign: `Map = Map1`...

Answer (score 0):

I personally would not write code like this, but for testing...

```
int main( )
{
    for( size_t i= 0; i < 10; ++i )
        std::cout << Map[ i ] << std::endl;

    memcpy( Map, Map1, sizeof( Map ) );

    for( size_t i= 0; i < 10; ++i )
        std::cout << Map[ i ] << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just leverage the built-in copy assignment for classes:

```
struct map {
    char Map[10][21];
};

map Map = { 
    "####################",
    "#                  #",
    "#                  #",
    "#                  #",
    "#                  #",
    "#                  #",
    "#                  #",
    "#                  #",
    "#                  #",
    "####################"
};

map Map1 = {
    "####################",
    "#                  #",
    "#                  #",
    "#                  #",
    "#                  #",
    "#       TEST       #",
    "#                  #",
    "#                  #",
    "#                  #",
    "####################"
};

int main()
{
    Map = Map1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying them, maybe it is more successful to exchange its contents, this can be done using `std::swap`

```
swap(Map,Map1);
```